# Ruby on Rails on IIS

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, iis, proxy, reverse-proxy

What is the best way to run Rails 3 on IIS 7?

1 example is to start rails server on 3000 port and use reverse proxy & url routing

Comment: Is it really necassary to use ISS? You can also run other webservers on windows systems.

Comment: yep, I really don't like what I am doing but it is necessary